# Como fazer laço com mensagem de objeto inválido?

Tags: c, validação, while

Estou fazendo esse programa apenas para treinar, e quero imprimir uma mensagem dizendo "objeto inválido" se o que eu digitar for diferente dos sólidos que estarão declarados nas variáveis, mas com um laço `while` para retornar para que eu possa digitar o sólido novamente. Porém se eu imprimir a mensagem de objeto inválido dentro da função `do` ele vai imprimir a primeira vez mesmo se eu digitar um objeto válido.

```
void main()
{
    system("cls");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int comp;
    float raio, alt;
    char sld[19];
    char cil[9] = "cilindro";

        printf("\t\t ========== Calculadora de Volume ==========");

        do
        {
            printf("\n\n Digite o sólido: ");
            fgets(sld, 61, stdin);
            fflush(stdin);

            comp = strcmp(sld, cil);
        } 
        while (comp != 0);
```

Comment: pode colocar a condição dentro de um if: `if (comp != 0) printf("objeto inválido");` simples assim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não faça uso do `do-while`, faça um laço infinito e tome uma decisão dentro se vai continuar ou não dentro do laço de acordo com a condição estabelecida, assim pode fazer o que deseja. Até dá para usar esta construção, mas ou tem que duplicar a condição, ou criar uma *flag* ou fazer um código bem confuso.

Aproveitei e consertei outros problemas do código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char sld[19];
    printf("\t\t ========== Calculadora de Volume ==========");
    while (1) {
        printf("\nDigite o sólido: ");
        fgets(sld, 18, stdin);
        sld[strcspn(sld, "\n")] = 0;
        if (strcmp(sld, "cilindro") == 0) break;
        printf("\nObjeto inválido");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/q55eaA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ExitConditionc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/WhileExit.c).